# HBase java API to write long instead of Hexadecimal values

Tags: java, shell, hbase

I am using Hbase Put API to write a long datatype to Hbase using the below code

```
p.add(Bytes.toBytes(this.hcol_fam_n), Bytes.toBytes(this.hcol_qual_n), Bytes.toBytes(this.newoffset));
```

When I run a scan command on Hbase shell, the values are displayed in hex format of binary representation

```
value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07
```

But when I use put statement from Hbase shell, it displays properly as "7".  Why is this difference? And Is there any way to write the value as is without using Bytes.toBytes to write to Hbase so that I can see the value properly from Hbase shell?

If there is no other way to write the value in readable form in hbase shell, how to invoke the java `Bytes.toString` here for this column in scan statement?

And when I read the same value using Hbase GET API, I am unable to convert value from Bytes to string using `Bytes.toString(value)`

This gives me null string. But the same value is getting converted to Long using `Bytes.toLong(value)`

Can someone please help me understand why this is not converting to string but to Long?

Comment: 'But when I use put statement from Hbase shell', by saying that, what's your statement ?

Answer (score 3):

HBase stores all values as byte arrays and doesn't store any metadata on what is the type of your data, so when you put a value of type `Long` it converts the value to it's bytes representation and writes the bytes to the cell.

When you do a Scan in the shell, it tries it's best to show you your data, but it doesn't know what type your data has. So it displays the bytes as chars, but if a byte is a control character it shows it's hex representation instead of displaying garbage in your console. And when you Get the data with `Bytes.toString`, again it doesn't know what kind of data is inside the cell and just makes `new String(bytes)`.

You have two options:

- convert your data to String before putting to HBase: 
  `p.add(colFamily, qualifier, Bytes.toBytes(Long.toString(this.newoffset)));` and when reading it convert back from String to Long. This adds some overhead for every read/write and consumes more space, but you'll have all your data human-readable in the shell.
- put your Long value directly as you do now and read it back with Bytes.toLong. This way your data generally consumes less space (always 8 bytes per value instead of up to 20) and is faster to read and write, but you'll still see it's hex representation in HBase shell.

Answer (score 0):

Best way way to handle this is convert the integer into string before storing it to hbase.I had same problem and solved this as given below:
new String( data.toString ).getBytes()